# CSS - word-wrap with input and label DOM elements

Tags: css, word-wrap

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WBZng/1/

I have a HTML structure that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <input/>
    <span>Label comes here...</span>
</div>
```

Both `input` and `span` should have `display:inline`. Also, `span` has `word-wrap:break-word` so that a long text without space still becomes wrapped. However, if the text is long, then the `<span>` is displayed in a new line instead of preserving `display:inline-block`. This is not an issue if there is a space in `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider giving `ellipsis` to the `span` element:

```
.panel span {
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WBZng/3/